# Can bitcoins be moved from the origin address to the origin address?

Tags: transactions, change

I ask this because it seems more efficient to send change to the original address instead of a new one. Does the cryptography not allow this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can bitcoins be moved from the origin address to the origin address?

Yes. There are no restrictions. (In fact there is no "addresses" in bitcoin protocol)

> it seems more efficient to send change to the original address

Why do you think that it can be more efficient? In fact it is not.

> Does the cryptography not allow this?

This is not related to cryptography at all.